# sql to query builder laravel 4 with multiple table select

Tags: laravel-4, query-builder

I would like to translate this sql request in query builder for laravel 4.2, could you help me?

Thanks in advance!

Table api_calls => id | key_id | server | created_at

Table api_key => id | key | created_at

SQL :

```
SELECT K.key FROM api_key as K

WHERE
(SELECT count(id) FROM api_calls WHERE server = $server AND key_id = K.id AND created_at >= $DateSeconds) < 10

AND 
(SELECT count(id) FROM api_calls WHERE server = $server AND key_id = K.id AND created_at >= $DateMinutes) < 500

GROUP BY K.key
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use joins ang aggregation like that:

```
DB::table('api_key as K')
    ->select('K.*')
    ->join('api_calls as ac1', function ($join) use ($server, $DateSeconds) {
        $join->on('ac1.server', '=', DB::raw($server));
        $join->on('ac1.key_id', '=', 'K.id');
        $join->on('ac1.created_at', '>=', DB::raw($DateSeconds));
     })
     ->join('api_calls as ac2', function ($join) use ($server, $DateMinutes) {
        $join->on('ac2.server', '=', DB::raw($server));
        $join->on('ac2.key_id', '=', 'K.id');
        $join->on('ac2.created_at', '>=', DB::raw($DateMinutes));
     })
     ->having(DB::raw('COUNT(ac1.id)'), '<', 10)
     ->having(DB::raw('COUNT(ac2.id)'), '<', 500)
     ->groupBy('K.id')
     ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you, i will test that tomorrow, have a nice day :)

Comment: Hello, thank you for this request but when i vardump the result i get nothing. Even not any error. Any idea?

Comment: Well in my opinion this query should work. If you get nothing it means that all the records been filter out. If you have Laravel's Debugbar you can check what is the result query. You can also try to check this one with `leftJoin()` (left outer join) instead of `join` (inner join) - to just check if there is any results.